# Function returns strange value when passed 0,0 on c#

Tags: c#, function

Ive been trying to code battleships as part of a college assignment but I'm running into a strange issue whilst testing. When I pass 0,0 as the coordinate, coordinate[1] returns 48 for some reason. Could anyone offer some help?

```
public static int[] getYXCoordinate(string coordinate)
{
    return new int[2] ((int)coordinate[2],(int)coordinate[0]); 
}
```

For the record, before any arguments are passed, they are validated to be in the form x,y.

Comment: coordinate is a string. coordinate[2] is the third char in the string. And casting those to int gives you the value of that char in the fitting encoding. When you look for an ASCII Chart for example you will see that the char '0' is at position 48 means it has the integer value of 48.Why is coordinate a string?

Comment: Should i use int.Parse() instead of (int)?

Comment: You should not use a string for representing a coordinate. A coordinate is a pair numbers. So use a pair of integer for example. The framework has a point class for example. Its just a struct containing an X,Y value pair. Fitting for a coordinate,location,point whatever you want to name it.

Comment: Ive got it working just using the int.Parse() but ill try out the integer pair, thanks so much for your help though <3

Comment: Try to sink the ship at "10,10" and see what happens.

Comment: @BinRohan No, `int.Parse` needs a `string`, not a `char`. Also you should not rely on the ecoordinates being 1-digit numbers. Better `Split` the string on the comma and pass the resulting substrings.

Comment: Ive got the board labeled 0-9, 0-9 to make it easier to regex, but I've tried testing it now and everything seems to be working flawlessly.

Comment: @KlausGütter I use a regex to validate the user input, and the range of the board is 0-9, meaning that it will always be one digit.

Comment: `return new int[2] (coordinate[2] - '0',coordinate[0] - '0'); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns `48` because you are returning the `char` itself. If you take a look into the [ASCII Table](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html?c=0) you see that the character `0` is represented as `48` in DEC

Also you may consider using the `Point` struct from `System.Drawing`

```
public static Point GetYXCoordinateFromString(string coordinate)
{
    //Splits the string at the ',' character
    //Will throw if there is not at least one ',' in the string
    var str = coordinate.Split(',');
    
    //Parses the two parts to ints and creates a new Point() struct out of it
    //Will throw if there are other chars then integers within the first or second part seperated by ','
    return new Point(int.Parse(str[0]), int.Parse(str[1])); 
}
```